# Setting the extents or bounds of "map view" of OpenLayers does not open the webpage at given Zoom Level

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When I load the map without any extent in my view, then the HTML page opens properly,
[image: without bounds]

```
      var myview = new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [77, 24],
            zoom: 4.5, 
            maxZoom: 8,
            minZoom: 3,
            smoothResolutionConstraint:true,
            //extent: [60, 6, 100, 40],
      });
```

but once I set the bounds in my view, it doesn't follow the given zoom level and opens differently
[image: with bounds]

```
      var myview = new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [77, 24],
            zoom: 4.5, 
            maxZoom: 8,
            minZoom: 3,
            smoothResolutionConstraint:true,
            extent: [60, 6, 100, 40],
      });
```

How should I change the JS so that, it opens at the given zoom level when I give the bound extents.

Comment: By default the extent setting means neither the width or height of the extent can be exceeded.  Include `showFullExtent: true,` in the options to change that so one but not both can be exceeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the specification of the view `extent` option, it says:

> The extent that constrains the view, in other words, nothing outside
> of this extent can be visible on the map.

In your case that means that nothing to the left of 60° and right of 100° longitude should be visible in the map view. Since at zoom 3 more would be visible, higher zoom is used to comply with the extent restriction.

If you want to limit viewable extent of a specific layer, use `extent` option when defining that layer.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, & I exactly want to keep the things within the bound that i have mentioned in the code [60, 6, 100, 40], nothing left of 60° and nothing right of 100°, similarly nothing above 40° and nothing below 6°. I think the code is right, the issue is with the map-view of HTML web-page.